# Получение значений из SpinBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qspinbox

Задано уравнение, по которому строится впоследствии график с помощью *Mpl*-виджета:

> y =T0+G*x-B*G*(1-np.exp(-x/B))+dT0*np.exp(-x/B)

Нужно на вход вместо задания начальных значений в коде для констант в уравнении получать значения из `SpinBox`'ов. Каким образом может выглядеть реализация?

Константы: `T0, G, B, dT0.`
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> value : int
>
> Это свойство содержит значение счетчика

```
self.spinBox.value()
```

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#value-prop

Comment: @ArtemKulagin что не так?

Comment: спасибо за ответ! пока что не проверил, скоро отпишу

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: @ArtemKulagin пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour